# Is the theory of categories decidable?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory, decidability

There are a lot of theorems in basic homological algebra, such as the five lemma or the snake lemma, that seem like they'd be more easily proven by computer than by hand.  This led me to consider the following question: **is the theory of categories decidable?**

More specifically, I was wondering whether or not statements about *abelian* categories can be determined true or false in finite time.  Also, if they can be determined to be false, is it possible to explicitly describe a counterexample?  If it is known to be decidable, is anything known about the complexity?  (Other decidable theories often have multiply-exponential time complexities.)  If it is known to be undecidable, say by embedding the halting problem, then can I change my assumptions a bit and make it decidable?  (For example, maybe I shouldn't be looking at abelian categories after all.)

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: It appears a clarification is needed.  My goal was to consider the minimal theory that could *state* things like the five lemma, but not necessarily prove them.  For example, I want to say:

> If in an abelian category, you have a bunch of maps $0\to A \to B \to C\to 0$ and $0\to A' \to B' \to C'\to 0$ which make up two short exact sequences and some more maps $a:A\to A'$, $b:B\to B'$, $c:C\to C'$ which commute with the previous maps, and $a$ and $c$ are isomorphisms, then $b$ is an isomorphism, too.

Sentences of this form would be inputs to a program, which decides if this statement is in fact true in ZFC (or your other favorite axiomatization of category theory).  The point here is that I am restricting the *sentences* one can input into the program, but keeping ZFC or whatnot as my framework.

I hoped (perhaps naively) that if I restricted the class of sentences, it might be decidable whether or not these statements were true.  For example, I imagined that every such theorem is either proven by diagram chasing, or it is possible to find a concrete example of maps among, say, R-modules that contradict the result.

Comment: Compare with this previous question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9930/algorithm-or-theory-of-diagram-chasing

Comment: @TC: It does seem related, but even more ambitious.  I should say that with my (not so extensive) knowledge of model theory it is not obvious how to formalize this decidability statement.  An abelian category is not a "relational structure" in the sense of model theory: in particular, there is no underlying set.  I would be interested to see a response which even gives a precise logical meaning to the question.

Comment: You'd need to first be precise about which first-order axiomatization of "the theory of categories" you mean.  Most mathematicians work from an axiomatization that starts with ZFC and adds more axioms about certain sets (which "are categories") existing.  This is, of course, not the only way to do things: you can axiomatize categories directly.  But how to do that is a matter of much debate; there is no clear agreement on which set of axioms to use (especially if you want to talk about __Set and __Cat__).

Comment: I was about to say the same thing that Adam said, but he said it first.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the question, but it made perfect sense to me. The theory of categories has two types O (objects) and A (arrows), the dom,cod:A -> O, a map id:O -> A, and a (possibly partial) operation comp:A x A -> A for composition. The axioms are pretty obvious. It's a bit strange to have a partial composition, but it's not the first time I've seen that happen. I think the same applies to Abelian categories.

Comment: I think you want the axioms in I.1 of Mac Lane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician* (p. 7 in my copy). The axioms for Abelian categories are given later on in Chapter VIII.

Comment: @Dorais: Yes, I think this must be the best way to think about it. Your language is the same as what I mentioned for a specific category in my answer. I was considering the decidability of the satisfaction relation in a single category---and you consider the decidability of provability in this theory. Surely this is also undecidable, since one can interpret the natural numbers in such a category, and then appeal to the "strong undecidability" property.

Comment: @Joel: I don't think it's that easy. My instinct would tell me to interpret the theory of groups or the theory of directed graphs. The problem is that the theory is not *essentially* undecidable, so I would prefer to interpret something which is finitely axiomatizable (and undecidable).

Comment: But it is fine, if you use *strongly undeciable* structures (in the precise technical sense), as I explain in my answer.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, that is a good idea. Now that I saw your argument, I see that another very quick solution is to directly translate the word problem using arrows.

Comment: This is a great question, deserving more votes (currently 2), in my opinion.

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins: Actually, it currently has four votes, except one of them is down.  =)  I think people took a dislike to the question because it may have been unclear what I meant and I wasn't around to clarify.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying your question. The formulation that
you and Dorais give seems perfectly reasonable. You have a
first order language for category theory, where you can
quantify over objects and morphisms, you can compose
morphisms appropriately and you can express that a given
object is the initial or terminal object of a given
morphism. In this language, one can describe various finite
diagrams, express whether or not they are commutative, and
so on. In particular, one can express that composition is
associative, etc. and describe what it means to be a
category in this way.

The question now becomes: is this theory decidable? In
other words, is there a computable procedure to determine,
given an assertion in this language, whether it holds in
all categories?

The answer is **No**.

One way to see this is to show even more: one cannot even
decide whether a given statement is true is true in all
categories having only one object. The reason is that group
theory is not a decidable theory. There is no computable
procedure to determine whether a given statement in the
first order language of group theory is true in all groups.
But the one-point categories naturally include all the
groups (and we can define in a single statement in the
category-theoretic language exactly what it takes for the
collection of morphisms on that object to be a group).
Thus, if we could decide category theory, then we could
decide the translations of the group theory questions into
category theory, and we would be able to decide group
theory, which we can't. Contradiction.

The fundamental obstacle to decidability here, as I
mentioned in my previous answer (see edit history), it the
ability to encode arithmetic. The notion of a [strongly
undecidable
structure](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnl/1235423985)
is key for proving various theories are undecidable. A
strongly undecidable theory is a finitely axiomatizable
theory, such that any theory consistent with it is
undecidable. Robinson proved that there is a strongly
undecidable theory of arithmetic, known as Robinson's Q. A
*strongly undecidable structure* is a structure modeling a
strongly undecidable theory. These structures are amazing,
for any theory true in a strongly undecidable structure is
undecidable. For example, the standard model of arithmetic,
which satisfies Q, is strongly undecidable. If A is
strongly undecidable and interpreted in B, then it follows
that B is also strongly undecidable. Thus, we can prove
that graph theory is undecidable, that ring theory is
undecidable and that group theory is undecidable, merely by
finding a graph, a ring or a group in which the natural
numbers is interpreted. Tarski found a strongly undecidable
group, namely, the group G of permutations of the integers
Z. It is strongly undecidable because the natural numbers
can be interpreted in this group. Basically, the number n
is represented by translation-by-n. One can identify the
collection of translations, as exactly those that commute
with s = translation-by-1. Then, one can define addition as
composition (i.e. addition of exponents) and the divides
relation is definable by: i divides j iff anything that
commutes with s<sup>i</sup> also commutes with
s<sup>j</sup>. And so on.

I claim similarly that there is a strongly undecidable
category. This is almost immediate, since every group can
be viewed as the morphisms of a one-object category, and
the group is interpreted as the morphisms of this category.
Thus, the category interprets the strongly undecidable
group, and so the category is also strongly undecidable. In
particular, any theory true in the category is also
undecidable. So category theory itself is undecidable.

Comment: A simpler answer: Any theory of categories that is "good enough" will also be able to axiomatize set theory, which means immediately that it's undecidable.

Comment: That is true, but one could ask for decidability even in a very restricted kind of category, which may not be able to interpret set theory. (For example, the category of finite graphs with induced subgraph mappings.) My point was that once you have number-like objects that can be added and multiplied (and quantified over), then you will get undecidability.

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins: Can you give me a reference for how to embed numbers/addition/multiplication into category-theoretical statements of the kind I or F. G. Dorais were describing?  Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, François!  I'm sorry to have misspelled your name back then. 

Answer (score 23):

This answer builds on those of F. G. Dorais and Joel David Hamkins to answer your "specific question", the question left open by them, namely whether the theory of *abelian* categories is decidable.

The answer is still **no**.

Even the following more limited family of problems is undecidable:

> Given words $r, r_1,\ldots,r_m$ in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ (i.e., each $r_i$ is a finite product of the $x_i$ and their inverses), decide whether it is true that whenever the $x_i$ are interpreted as automorphisms of an object $M$ in an abelian category, $r_1=\cdots=r_m=1_M$ implies $r=1_M$.

If the answer to the corresponding instance of the word problem for finitely presented groups is yes, then the answer to this abelian category question is yes.
Conversely if the answer to the word problem instance is no, then we can construct the finitely presented group $G = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n | r_1,\ldots,r_m \rangle$, form the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$, and let $M$ be $\mathbb{Z}G$ as a module over itself, which shows that the answer to the abelian category question is no too.

So if there were an algorithm to decide this family of abelian category problems, there would also be an algorithm to decide the word problem for finitely presented groups.  But P. S. Novikov proved in 1955 that the latter algorithm does not exist.

Comment: Excellent! A neat trick...

Comment: Sorry, what is r?

Comment: It's just another word, a relation for which you would like to decide whether it is a consequence of the others.  (I just omitted the "r," in the boxed statement, but now it's there.)

Answer (score 14):

The theory of categories is undecidable. By the theory of categories I mean the theory with two types Ob (objects) and Ar (arrows) together with operations dom:Ar → Ob, cod:Ar → Ob, 1:Ob → Ar, and o:Ar×Ar→Ar (possibly partial composition), and the obvious axioms.

One way to see this is to interpret the theory of groups — which is undecidable by a beautiful theorem of Trakhtenbrot — within the theory of pointed categories, that is categories with a distinguished object * (which is an inessential extension). Indeed, the *definable* set of invertible arrows from * to * form a group, and every group can be interpreted as the set of arrows in a category with * as its only object. I suspect that the theory of Abelian categories is not decidable either, but I haven't tried to prove that (yet).

Comment: Oh, it looks like you and I hit on the same idea. I was editing my answer when you posted yours!

Comment: Yep, I think we got it right this time! I'm not sure about Abelian categories anymore. I don't use them enough to know what to do.

Comment: Of course, abelian group theory is a decidable theory. But it seems that abelian category theory could be powerful enough for undecidability.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the objects of a category form a set (i.e., the category is small)?  Could you clarify why this is a reasonable restriction?  

Comment: @Pete: This problem arises with all theories, e.g. monster models are better thought of as proper classes than just very large sets. This poses no real problem, except for foundational theories such as Set Theory and Category Theory which have a deeper philosophical meaning. The "workaround" for Category Theory is exactly the same as that for Set Theory...

Comment: @Pete: Very interesting question! We interpreted the question as whether the given first order theory is decidable, whether one can compute if a given statement is provable in the theory. By the Completeness Theorem, a statement is provable if and only if it holds in all set-sized categories, as you mention. I claim that in ZFC, this is the same as the set of validites in all class-sized categories, by the Reflection theorem: any statement true in a class, is also true in restriction of that class to a set, some large V_alpha. A similar Lowenheim-Skolem argument works with universes.

Comment: @F. G. Dorais: Thanks for your answer.  I've accepted @Joel David Hamkins's answer, because the answers were nearly simultaneous and I can only accept one ...

Comment: On the other hand, there is no reason for the equational fragment of the theory of categories _without automorphisms_ be undecidable, and it is actually decidable, see "http://mishap.sdf.org/mints-a-decidable-fragment-of-category-theory-without-automorphisms.pdf