# The sharp 3x3 lemma: a proof by universal properties?

Tags: homological-algebra, diagram-chase

I was reading [this paper](http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/PUBLICACIONSMATEMATIQUES_1989_33_01_10.pdf) a while ago, and I couldn't figure out how to prove a lemma that was left as an exercise by only using universal properties and the definition of an abelian category.

I'll reproduce the diagram:

$$\ \ \matrix{
&&0&&0&&0
\cr&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow
\cr &&A_1 & & B_1& &C_1
\cr &&\downarrow & &\downarrow&&\downarrow
\cr &&A_2 & \to & B_2 & \to & C_2 &
\cr &&\downarrow &&\downarrow&&\downarrow
\cr 0&\to&A_3 & \to & B_3 & \to & C_3
}\ \ $$

With all rows and columns exact. (This diagram lives in an abelian category).

Show that there exists an exact sequence $A_1\to B_1\to C_1$ making the diagram commute.

Sure, it's not too hard with elements, I mean, it's just part of the snake lemma.  However, proving it with universal properties is another story.  By the universal property of the kernel, there are natural maps $A_1 \to B_1$, and $B_1 \to C_1$. Proving that this is exact is another story entirely.  I believe I was able to show (I tried this a few months ago) that the top left corner (not counting zeros) is cartesian (a pullback square), but I still couldn't prove exactness.

I repeat, this is for a proof without elements.  It should rely only on the definition of an abelian category and universal properties.  If you happened not to click the link to the paper, the whole point is a proof *without elements*.  I'd really like to see at least one proof in homological algebra actually done from the definition, just because it would be extremely instructive.

Comment: The fact that the top left corner will be cartesian is straightforward to prove.  I'm pretty sure of it.

Comment: You can remove $C_3$ and the two arrows through it from your diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should follow from the Salamander lemma, which, as you found out in your [previous MO question,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6749/a-proof-of-the-salamander-lemma-without-mitchells-embedding-theorem) can be proved without the use of elements. It is a nice exercise, so I won't spell it out for you.

Comment: I don't remember ever getting an answer to that question.

Comment: Did you see that Jonathan Wise added a section on the salamander lemma to the notes he wrote up for your question?

Comment: Nope.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I never was notified of the update by the system.

Comment: The proof using the Salamander Lemma makes it clear you can remove C_3 from the diagram. 

Answer (score 6):

Consider the total complex of the picture (thought of as a bicomplex).  Since the vertical sequences are exact, the total complex is exact.  Since the bottom rows are exact, the cohomology of the total complex is the cohomology of the top row, by the spectral sequence for a bicomplex.  So the top row is exact.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_sequence#The_spectral_sequence_of_a_double_complex



Comment: So you're suggesting to try to construct the spectral sequence of a bicomplex without using the 3 x 3 lemma? 

Comment: I don't think contructing the spectral sequence should be a problem.  There's a greater chance that the 3 x 3 lemma is used in the proof that the spectral sequence converges to the right thing, but I don't really see why. 

Comment: I'm not saying it is impossible, but my recollection is that in both the exact couple method and the usual method, when you pass to the next page of the spec. seq. and define the new differential, you usually do a diagram chase to show it is well defined. While not exactly the same as the 3 x 3 lemma, my recollection is that this diagram chase is roughly of about the same complexity. 

Comment: The proof above doesn't quite work, because the bottom rows are not exact if you take into account the implicit zeroes at all the other lattice points of the plane.  The same remark applies to the columns, but that can be fixed by adding a fourth row of cokernels of the vertical maps entering the third row.

Comment: To fix the proof, look at the differentials coming out  of the $B_1$ spot.  On page 1, it goes to the $B_2$ spot, which is zero, because of the horizontal exactness there.  On page 2, it goes to the $A_3$ spot, which is zero, because of the horizontal exactness there.  Thus it survives forever, hence must already be zero on page 1, because the abutment is zero, yielding the result.